How to use NiFi (1.25) JSLTTransformJSON processor to get specific fields from an array as a single entry
I have JSON input from which I want to pull out the same sub-elements of arrays into one field. Trying to figure how to structure JSLT using NiFi JSLTTransformJSON processor.
Input:
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "ID": "123123123",
  "address": [
    {
      "location": "123 Main, Citty, ST",
      "info": {
        "type": "single family",
        "own": "yes"
      }
    },
    {
      "location": "123 Lane, Wonderland, ST",
      "info": {
        "type": "apartment",
        "own": "yes"
      }
    },
    {
      "location": "123 Street, Place, ST",
      "info": {
        "type": "condo",
        "own": "no"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Desired output:
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "ID": "123123123",
  "residence_type": "single family, apartment, condo"
}

Desired output where the info.own == "yes" :
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "ID": "123123123",
  "residence_type": "123 Main, Citty, ST; 123 Lane, Wonderland, ST"
}

where I don't know how many addresses there might be.

For the first desired output:
{

  
  "residence_type":join([for (.address) .info.type],", "),
  "address":null,
  *:.

}

For the second desired output:
{

  
  "residence_type":join([for (.address) .location if(.info.own=="yes")],", "),
  "address":null,
  *:.

}

If you are trying to combine both based on the info.own  value:
{

  
  "residence_type":join([for (.address) .location if(.info.own=="yes")]+[for (.address) .info.type if(.info.own!="yes")] ,"; "),
  "address":null,
  *:.

}

if you are getting the info.own as flowfile attribute you can include in the JSLT spec using Expression Language and use jslt function to drive the output:
def residence_type(info_own)
    
    if($info_own=="yes")
    
       join([for (.address) .location if(.info.own=="yes")],"; ")
    
    else
    
       join([for (.address) .info.type],", ")
    
    
    {
    
    
      "residence_type":residence_type("${info.own}"),
      "address":null,
      *:.
    
    }

Hope that helps.
